# Remove half part of Page

Tags: spacing

How can I remove second half part of the page. For example my conclusion is half of page and I want reference list  starts at the same page. My reference list starts one page after conclusion, but what I want is to let References list starts at the same page as conclusion. How can I do this please.

Comment: Could you please add a minimum (working) example to your post? It would help the solvers a lot to start working on it. I would redefine `\newpage`, `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` locally in group.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. We need more information to answer your question. Were you using `article`, for example, the bibliography would not start a new page. Unless we know what you are doing, it is hard to tell you what you would need to change to get the effect you want. All questions should include code for a complete small document demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Usually Reference makes use of `\chapter*` which starts a new page (or two).

Answer (score 3):

Surely you are using a document class (like the standard `book`) where the bibliography starts a new page since a `\chapter*` command is issued (or similar).

A solution could be to redefine `\clearpage` (the command responsible of the new page) locally to the bibliography, so that the latter doesn't start a new page, something like

```
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\endgroup
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{auth00a,
  author = {Author, A},
  journal = {Journal A},
  title = {MyBook A},
  year = {2000}
}
@article{auth00b,
  author = {Author, B},
  journal = {Journal B},
  title = {MyBook B},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\nocite{*}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]